# elasticsearch.bat terminal getting hung up?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm running the elasticsearch 8.1.0 batch file for the first time and the terminal is getting hung up at this line for several hours without progressing. I'm expecting that after the .bat finishes, I'll be provided with the initial username/password I need to log in to elastic.

[date/time][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [computer name] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.security-7][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.security-7][0]]"

I tried changing the network and http hosts variables in elastcsearch.yaml but it seemed to have no impact.

Comment: Elasticsearch will only show you the password on the first time it starts, so if you missed it you need to remove the data directory and start it again

Comment: the program has gotten hung up on this line every time i've ran it (including the first time), so i still have never seen the password

Comment: at that point Elasticsearch is up and running and is available for requests